# Change row color when item changes

Tags: rowcolor

Following the idea in this post:
http://www.benjaminbiegel.com/a-latex-table-that-actually-looks-nice-2-106.html
I was able to create this table:

[image]

It changes the rowcolor for every row, and I need it to change when a new word (in column 2) is entered. So the two rows of "joya" would be 'green' and the seven rows of "juicio" would be light-brown. 
Is there a "counter" that changes the row color when the word-item (in second column) changes?
The code I use is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{TableBorder}{RGB} {255,211,32}
\definecolor{TableOdd}   {RGB} {204,153,0}
\definecolor{TableEven}  {RGB} {168,166,0}
\definecolor{colortexto} {RGB} {5,36,62}
%
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}
%
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{TableOdd}{TableEven}          

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
!{\color{TableBorder}\VRule[1pt]}           
>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l                   
!{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l                   
!{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l                   
!{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l                   
!{\color{TableBorder}\vline}>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l 
!{\color{TableBorder}\vline}>{\bf\color{colortexto}}l
!{\color{TableBorder}\VRule[1pt]}}          

\arrayrulecolor{TableBorder}                
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
\rowcolor{TableOdd}                         
Rating&concepto&subconcepto&página&idea&capítulo\\ 
\specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
$\varheartsuit$ $\varheartsuit$&jardín&&337&mujer buena como un jardín&XXXIII – I\\
\hline  
$\varheartsuit$ $\varheartsuit$&jaula&&487&voy encantado por envidia&XLVII – I\\
\hline  
&joya&&393&paz (la)&XXXVII – I\\       
&&&519&que si se pierde …&LI – I\\
\hline     
&juicio&&1087&con más juicio discurría&LXXI – II\\
&&&493&confuso juicio del vulgo& XLVIII – I\\
&&&334&discurso (sin) y temerario&XXXIII – I\\
$\varheartsuit$&&&572&gran juicio para componer historias& III – II\\
&&&512&justicia (buen juicio para administrar justicia)&L – I\\
&&&1100&libre (tengo juicio ya libre)& LXXIV – II\\
&&&554&volverme mi juicio&I – II\\
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Any idea will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: The `\rowcolor` has to be set within the first column. So, if you're willing to change the layout then it's probably doable. However, for such a small table, I'd suggest just setting the `\rowcolor` manually.

Comment: I put this small example just to show my need, but I really have 28 tables, some of which are of little more than 300 rows (93 pages), so "manually" would be a nightmare...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `\rowcolor` as the first item in a row, so you have to input the first two row items together.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{TableBorder}{RGB} {255,211,32}
\definecolor{TableOdd}   {RGB} {204,153,0}
\definecolor{TableEven}  {RGB} {168,166,0}
\definecolor{colortexto} {RGB} {5,36,62}

\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}
\newcommand{\RC}[2]{%
  % #1 is the rating, #2 is the concept;
  % if #2 is empty, it is assumed to repeat the previous one
  \rowcolor{\TableEvenOrOdd}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
  \else
    \stepcounter{rowcolors}%
  \fi
  #1 & #2
}
\newcommand{\TableEvenOrOdd}{%
  \ifodd\value{rowcolors}TableEven\else TableOdd\fi
}
\newcounter{rowcolors}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  !{\color{TableBorder}\VRule[1pt]}           
  >{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l                   
  !{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
  >{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l                   
  !{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
  >{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l                   
  !{\color{TableBorder}\vline}
  >{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l                   
  !{\color{TableBorder}\vline}>{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l 
  !{\color{TableBorder}\vline}>{\bfseries\color{colortexto}}l
  !{\color{TableBorder}\VRule[1pt]}}          

\arrayrulecolor{TableBorder}                
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
\rowcolor{TableOdd}                         
Rating&concepto&subconcepto&página&idea&capítulo\\ 
\specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0pt}                 
\RC{$\varheartsuit$ $\varheartsuit$}{jardín}&&337&mujer buena como un jardín&XXXIII – I\\
\hline  
\RC{$\varheartsuit$ $\varheartsuit$}{jaula}&&487&voy encantado por envidia&XLVII – I\\
\hline  
\RC{}{joya}&&393&paz (la)&XXXVII – I\\       
\RC{}{}&&519&que si se pierde …&LI – I\\
\hline
\RC{}{juicio}&&1087&con más juicio discurría&LXXI – II\\
\RC{}{}&&493&confuso juicio del vulgo& XLVIII – I\\
\RC{}{}&&334&discurso (sin) y temerario&XXXIII – I\\
\RC{$\varheartsuit$}{}&&572&gran juicio para componer historias& III – II\\
\RC{}{}&&512&justicia (buen juicio para administrar justicia)&L – I\\
\RC{}{}&&1100&libre (tengo juicio ya libre)& LXXIV – II\\
\RC{}{}&&554&volverme mi juicio&I – II\\
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

A counter steps only if the second argument to `\RC` is not empty.

[image]

I changed `txfonts` into the better combination of `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`; also `\bf`, which has been deprecated for more than 20 years, should be `\bfseries`.

Comment: Just what I needed! Works wonderfully! Thank you egreg :-)